# How to make Wicket modal dialog only in java

Tags: java, modal-dialog, wicket

Is there any way, how to create modal dialog in Wicket only in Java, that means dont declare modal window in HTML template? Thanks for help.

Comment: It depends on what kind of modal you want :-). A simple modal can be created using basic 'alert' js function and deciding on Java side when it should be displayed. For example: https://wicket-guide.herokuapp.com/scriptposition/

Comment: No, I need modal dialog with yes/cancel buttons.

Comment: Again, if you are ok with a basic version you can use 'confirm' function:

confirm('Are you sure you want it?')

Please give more details on what you'd like to achieve

Comment: I need to do some funkcionality if user choose ok, and some fukcionality if user hit cancel. I dont know how to check, which button user click in javascript.